# Google Cloud and Google.Cloud.Functions.Framework

Tags: .net, .net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Google Cloud function with .net core and Google.Cloud.Functions.Framework to log user activity. I've considered to use DB to store these activities, however at first step I will try to store it in simple text file on google storage (is it proper from architectural point of view?).

My question is how can I write to google bucket using .net core and google function (my function is triggered on HTTP) and looks simple like this

```
    public async Task HandleAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
         //code goes here
         await context.Response.WriteAsync("Activity logged");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the [Google.Cloud.Storage.V1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/) NuGet package ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/latest)), just as you would from any other environment. (There's nothing special here in terms of Google Cloud Functions - authentication should work out of the box without any extra credentials.)

We have a [sample function](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-dotnet/tree/main/examples/Google.Cloud.Functions.Examples.StorageImageAnnotator) that integrates both Google Cloud Storage and the Vision API, which includes uploading a file to Google Cloud Storage.

I would recommend using [dependency injection via a FunctionsStartup class](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-dotnet/blob/main/docs/customization.md) to configure the `StorageClient`, then you should be able to just upload an object to the bucket in a straightforward way.

Comment: Thanks, that works great. One more question, is there simple way to append line to text file instead on creating it from the scratch? Is see the method _storageClient.UpdateObjectAsync, but I'm not sure how to use it. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Shark: That's really a very different question - it would normally be better to ask in a new question. But no, there's no simple way to do that. (UpdateObject is for the metadata, not the actual data.) It's possible that you could use the underlying composition API for this, but fundamentally I suspect you'd be better off with an alternative approach such as using a Firestore database.